# Orthographic from Perspective Photograph

Tags: image, orthographic

Is there any way (perhaps within Blender or any other tool) to obtain orthographic images from a couple of photographs in perspective? That would be extremely helpful as not always you have the "luxury" of orthographic blue-prints or images. Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Can you be a more specific about subject of photograhs? - environment, object, ... ilustrative image would be helpfull to understand. I can imagine only reconstruct 3D from photos and render as ortho. Are the images of the same subject or each single image is about something else?

Comment: In this particular case is a boat. I only have a couple of different perspective angles. I recognize there will have be be a lot of "artistic" interpretation. Just wonder if there is a technique or tool that would help to come up with an orthographic sketch from those photographs.

Comment: From single image you can reconstruct camera (https://fspy.io with export to blender, previously this was an addon) and try model a boat manually. For multiple images try some photogrametry app https://www.3dnatives.com/en/photogrammetry-software-190920194/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to take a perspective photo of something fairly planar with right-angle lines (shown at angles to each other in the perspective photo), and re-project the photo so that these angles are orthogonal to each other without the perspective shift?

I haven't figured out how to do it in blender yet, but Hugin (free and I believe open source panorama tool) can do it. Here's a tutorial that describes how.

https://hugin.sourceforge.io/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml

Comment: Unfortunately links to tutorials can expire which can invalidate your answer and render it as "low quality post" so it is best to explain your answer within this post on how this tool can be used to solve the OP's issue. Simply giving a link to a tutorial is not enough.